# histChanging Class in R for Column Name

Tags: r, data-mining, data-science

I have found many helpful pages on how to change a class in R but all have seemed to not work for my task.

Below is the code I'm using with output:

```
   > mydata = read.table("Books_R_Data.csv", header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=TRUE,sep=",")

  > hist(mydata)
  Error in hist.default(mydata) : 'x' must be numeric

   > head(mydata)
      NOMINAL SIDE
      1 3000000  BUY
      2 8000000  BUY
      3 4000000  BUY
      4 6300000  BUY
      5 2000000  BUY
      6 1000000  BUY

    > apply(mydata,2,class)
      NOMINAL        SIDE 
     "character" "character" 

    > mydata$NOMINAL = as.numeric(mydata$NOMINAL)

    > apply(mydata,2,class)
     NOMINAL        SIDE 
    "character" "character"
```

The above is the common method I have come across to fix the issue but as one can see, the class is still character. I'm only trying to change the NOMINAL column name to NUMERIC.

Thanks

Comment: Use `lapply` and don't use `apply` as it convert to `matrix`.  `lapply(mydata, class)`

Comment: thank you! I believe I have it figured out now.

Answer (score 0):

In your console, type: `help(hist)` to see what kind of arguments it expects. We see:

```
hist(x, ...)
```

and

```
x   a vector of values for which the histogram is desired.
```

You are passing it a dataframe. Try:

```
hist(mydata$NOMINAL)
```